# Implode on multiarray

Tags: php, arrays

I have array:

```
$array = array(
   0 => array('first' => 'aaa',
              'second' => 'bbb'),
   1 => array('first' => 'erw',
              'second' => 'wer'),
   2 => array('first' => 'aaawe',
              'second' => '345'),
   3 => array('first' => 'aa345a',
              'second' => 'dfgdfg'),
);
```

and i would like get values with implode:

```
$first = implode(';', $array['first']);
$second = implode(';', $array['second']);
```

But of course this not working. How is the best way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PHP 5.5 there exists a function `array_column()`: http://php.net/array_column

```
$first = implode(';', array_column($array, 'first'));
// same for $second
```

P.s.: for backwards compability check also https://github.com/ramsey/array_column out

---

As requested, something "simple" (PHP 5.3 compatible):

```
$first = array_reduce($array, function ($array, $string) { return ($string !== null?"$string;":"").$array['first']; }, null);
```

Comment: @josh4356 see my _p.s._ part: https://raw.github.com/ramsey/array_column/master/src/array_column.php is the array_column implementation for elder versions.

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for something simple :) This is too long code

Comment: @josh4356 is that better?

Comment: ok, thanks for help, but i use PHP <5.3, but i accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it without `array_column();`

```
<?php
 $array = array(
   0 => array('first' => 'aaa',
              'second' => 'bbb'),
   1 => array('first' => 'erw',
              'second' => 'wer'),
   2 => array('first' => 'aaawe',
              'second' => '345'),
   3 => array('first' => 'aa345a',
              'second' => 'dfgdfg'),
);
foreach ($array as $row)
{
  $values[] = $row['first'];
  $val[] = $row['second'];
}
$first= implode(',', $values);
$second= implode(',', $val);
echo $first."<br>";
echo $second;
?>
```

i tested and this gave me output

```
aaa,erw,aaawe,aa345a
bbb,wer,345,dfgdfg
```